# How to force set QTimeEdit's display to 24 hour format?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am developing an application by PyQt5. It contains a QTimeEdit for user to input time in `HH:mm` format.

However, I found out that the format of the QTimeEdit was following the Windows's setting. Which means, if I run the application on a Windows machine with date time formatting setting as 12-hour format, the QTimeEdit will show something like `1:59 PM` instead of `13:59`, and that is not I wanted.

Is there a way to force set the QTimeEdit format to 24 hour format regardless of Windows's setting?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I accidentally found the solution for it, using

```py
theQTimeEditObject.setDisplayFormat("HH:mm")
```

works under different Windows settings!

Comment: @musicamante Yes I did found the solution in the documentation. Btw the one you posted was for C++, [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDateTimeEdit.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat) is the one for python

Comment: That is almost irrelevant. Except for rare cases, specific to argument references that are not possible for python, 99.9% of functions work *exactly* in the same way as in C++ for Python. Besides, your link refers to PySide, and while it works *almost* like PyQt, it's **not** the same thing (in some rare occasions, arguments and/or returned types might differ, and there are some differences in implementation of magic methods), so, if you're using PyQt, always use the basic (C++) API documentation, and eventually refer to the `help()` command in the python interactive consolle.